# Is it possible to mount docker volume to a different filesystem?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm mounting a folder from my host machine which has about 20GB of mongodb files. Mongo is unable to start because it says there isn't enough space. It appears that the volume is being mounted into tmpfs instead of using the hard disk. Is there any way to change the filesystem for a volume?

docker-compose:

```
    mongo:
    image: mongo:2.4
    volumes:
        - /data/db:/data/db
```

Docker output

```
mongo_1  | Wed May  4 20:55:12.591 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
```

Machine memory:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            1025388  241788    783600  24% /data/db
/dev/vda2       61886452 1128580  57591152   2% /data/configdb
/dev/vda2       61886452 1128580  57591152   2% /etc/resolv.conf
/dev/vda2       61886452 1128580  57591152   2% /etc/hostname
/dev/vda2       61886452 1128580  57591152   2% /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Just had a quick read of the doco and I don't think this should happen. Check the mongo image Dockerfile whether it does something wonky.

Comment: I'm using the official mongo docker - https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/4bb17b336a05ad85c9bf83b103d21529e27e62f9/3.2/Dockerfile. Nothing stands out as wonky. The only thing new is that I'm using the new docker mac beta which replaces virtualbox.

Comment: Just ran the image on my Docker host with _docker run --rm -it -v ~/data:/data/db mongo:2.4 bash_ then ran _df_: **/dev/mapper/vg_root-root     29939424 6139352  23800072  21% /data/db**

Comment: Thanks for trying it. That must mean it's an issue with the new docker mac beta. I've filed a ticket with them.

Comment: Want me to put it up as an answer for closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be an issue with the Docker beta on your Mac.

Running Docker on Centos 7.x, I did:

```
mkdir ~/data
docker run --rm -it -v ~/data:/data/db mongo:2.4 bash
```

From inside the container I then checked

```
# df
```

And got

```
...
/dev/mapper/vg_root-root 29939424 6139352 23800072 21% /data/db
...
```

As you would expect. It's not mapped to tmpfs.